# Cygwin trimming trailing whitespace

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, cygwin

I am trying to write a personal webscraper for fun in unix. I have scraped a list of names and saved them to a file called "names". Secondly I mapped (mapfile index < names ) to an array all of the --> `while(count -lt ... ) do ${index[$count]}` would be how I call a single element within the array.

However I am having trouble because the mapfile added a trailing space to all elements within the array. Something like "AAPL ". I am wondering how to use a combination of sed, grep, and awk to trim the white space and if possible save the element back into the array.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give an extract of names file: for example output of `head names | od -c -tu1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are indexing the array from a file, you can make use of bracket expression with `sed`:

```
mapfile -t index < <(sed 's/[[:space:]]*//g' names)
```

alternatively `read` can be another approach:

```
read -a index <<< $(sed 's/[[:space:]]*//g' names)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was very new to the mapfile command and was unaware of the -t option. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Does -t resolve your problem or the sed?

Comment: As a quick test, run `cat -e FILE | head` to see if you have a line ending problem. If files end in CR LF instead of LF alone, you may see a blank at the end of the line where the CR appears. You can fix the file using `dos2unix FILE` or `d2u FILE`.